# How can I determine if an "NFT" I purchased was issued with an ERC20 token or ERC721 token?

Tags: solidity, nft

I am trying to determine if the NFT I own is an ERC20 token, or what it should be, an ERC721 token.  Here is the link to the contract and the link to the source code. It's on the C chain of Avalanche written w/Solidity.

https://cchain.explorer.avax.network/address/0xE935193fE3E9580f6796302C5F33a1f6Cc1A7b4E/transactions

https://cchain.explorer.avax.network/address/0xE935193fE3E9580f6796302C5F33a1f6Cc1A7b4E/contracts

Answer (score 0):

The only way to truly verify this is to look at the code of the smart contract and take no chances (which is 500 lines and I'm not going to spend time doing that right now).

You can then validate that the interface is what you want (ERC721 in this case), and that the implementation code implements this interface satisfactorily (for example there's no point in a function named transfer if it does something entirely different like minting tokens).

By clicking on `read contract` and `write contract` on the [token page](https://cchain.explorer.avax.network/address/0xE935193fE3E9580f6796302C5F33a1f6Cc1A7b4E/transactions), you can get an overview of what functions are available.

I can already see that the function `ownerOf` is missing, which should be available if following the official [ERC721 standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721).

It also has some balance-related functions which are more often found in `ERC20`-like tokens.

Comment: I really appreciate this response. Are you a dev that is interested in taking on a for hire project to write a new smart contract?

Comment: Perhaps. Feel free to email my crypto address: 0xa3bab7a95ed40c2a62c7a1ac4ef2043f8b7a1cb6@ethmail.cc

Comment: @CR If you are still looking for smart contract developers, I have little free time, but you can get in touch with me here: https://www.linkedin.com/in/davidpcallanan/